# how to make autocomplete text field in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to have a text field with AJAX auto-complete data in La ravel
I have done it in simple php but that doesn't workout for me.
Please help.

Comment: you'd better put some code

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+auto-complete

Answer (score -1):

There is a good plugin for you that calls https://select2.org/, maybe it works for you.